# Print the difference result between two counters in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have two counters whose results are displayed in a small part of the GUI for reference, but the important data I need is the result of IN minus OUT. For example, if I have 113 IN and 86 OUT, I am going to display those two data but I need to display also the result, 27 (113-86=27).

[Screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqyC1.png)

Given these two counters:

```
def counter_label_IN(label):
  def count():
    s.sendall(b'gcounters\x00')
    L_IN = next(iter(s.recv(1024)))
    print(L_IN)
    label_IN.config(text=str(L_IN))
    label_IN.after(500, count)
    
  count()

def counter_label_OUT(label):
  def count():
    s.sendall(b'gcounters\x00')
    L_OUT = next(iter(s.recv(1024)))
    print(L_OUT)
    label_OUT.config(text=str(L_OUT))
    label_OUT.after(500, count)
    
  count()
```

How can I have another timer keeping refreshing the difference between the two?
Also, if the difference is a negative number, I need to display only 0.

**EDIT after @j_4321 kind reply.**

Thank you so much for the reply. I am a little lost and I guess it is one of those time the reply is right in front of my eyes but it is so bright that I can't see it... The code written gives no error, but the counts displayed in all the labels are zeroes. This is a simplified code, but still you can see the 0:

**EDIT 2 after  @j_4321 kind reply.**

As suggested, I added:

```
counter_label_IN()
counter_label_OUT()
```

To the code, which I am pasting here for your consideration. It now gives me this error:

```
PS C:\Users\lorenzo.amati> & C:/Users/lorenzo.amati/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/lorenzo.amati/Desktop/Software PCN/PCN-local-getdata-prova.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/lorenzo.amati/Desktop/Software PCN/PCN-local-getdata-prova.py", line 55, in <module>
    counter_label_IN()
  File "c:/Users/lorenzo.amati/Desktop/Software PCN/PCN-local-getdata-prova.py", line 38, in counter_label_IN
    count()
  File "c:/Users/lorenzo.amati/Desktop/Software PCN/PCN-local-getdata-prova.py", line 27, in count
    s.sendall(b'gcounters\x00')
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Here is the code:

```
import socket
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# Main settings

IP_address = ('172.16.0.103')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("People Counter")
root.configure(bg="#006bb3")

font1 = "-family {Source sans pro} -size 36 -weight bold"
font2 = "-family {Source sans pro} -size 150 -weight bold"

# use IntVar as counters
counter_IN = tk.IntVar(root)
counter_OUT = tk.IntVar(root)
counter_DIFF = tk.IntVar(root)

# get the sensor data
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((IP_address,5400))

def counter_label_IN():
    def count():
        s.sendall(b'gcounters\x00')
        L_IN = next(iter(s.recv(1024)))
        print(L_IN)
        counter_IN.set(L_IN)  # update counter IntVar instead of label
        # update DIFF counter:
        diff = L_IN - counter_OUT.get()
        if diff < 0:
            diff = 0
        counter_DIFF.set(diff)
        label_IN.after(500, count)

    count()

def counter_label_OUT():
    def count():
        s.sendall(b'gcounters\x00')
        L_OUT = next(iter(s.recv(1024)))
        print(L_OUT)
        counter_OUT.set(L_OUT)  # update counter IntVar instead of label
        diff = counter_IN.get() - L_OUT
        if diff < 0:
            diff = 0
        counter_DIFF.set(diff)
        label_OUT.after(500, count)

    count()
s.close()

counter_label_IN()
counter_label_OUT()

# In/Out Informations display on top

FrameTOP = tk.Frame(root, bg="#006bb3", borderwidth="0")
FrameTOP.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')

Label_RTC_IN = tk.Label(FrameTOP, anchor='w',bg="#006bb3", fg='white',justify='left', text='Realtime count of people IN:')
Label_RTC_OUT = tk.Label(FrameTOP, anchor='w',bg="#006bb3", fg='white',justify='left', text='Realtime count of people OUT:')
label_IN = tk.Label(FrameTOP, textvariable=counter_IN, anchor='w',bg="white",fg="black", justify='left', relief='sunken', borderwidth="2")
label_OUT = tk.Label(FrameTOP, textvariable=counter_OUT, anchor='w',bg='white', fg='black', justify='left', relief='sunken', borderwidth="2")

Label_RTC_IN.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
label_IN.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
Label_RTC_OUT.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
label_OUT.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

# Frame in which to put the differential data of people inside

FrameCENTRAL = tk.Frame(root, bg="#006bb3",borderwidth="0")
FrameCENTRAL.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=50, columnspan=4,) #sticky='nsew')

TitleCentral = tk.Label(FrameCENTRAL,anchor='w', bg="#006bb3", fg='white', font=font1, text='''People Inside''')
TitleCentral.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

label_DIFF = tk.Label(FrameCENTRAL, textvariable=counter_DIFF, font=font2, bg="#006bb3", fg='white',  anchor='center')
label_DIFF.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

# IP Informations

FrameBOTTOM = tk.Frame(root, bg="#006bb3", borderwidth="0")
FrameBOTTOM.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')

Label_IP_ADDRESS = tk.Label(FrameBOTTOM,anchor='w',bg="#006bb3",fg='white',text='''People counter sensor locally connected to local IP address:''')
Label_IP = tk.Label(FrameBOTTOM,anchor='w',bg="#006bb3",fg='white',text=(IP_address))

Label_IP_ADDRESS.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
Label_IP.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# Closing button

close = tk.Button(FrameBOTTOM, bg="#006bb3",fg='white',text='Stop and close', width=16, command=root.destroy)
close.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, sticky='e')


root.mainloop()
```

[Screenshot of the app after the modification, showing all 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjBYq.png)

Comment: have you tried using the `textvariable` option available to `Entry()` widget in tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IntVar` as the IN, OUT and DIFF = IN - OUT counters and use the `textvariable` option of the `Label` to automatically update the text when updating the counters. In the `counter_label_...()` functions, the `IntVar` value will be updated instead of updating the label's text.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# use IntVar as counters
counter_IN = tk.IntVar(root)
counter_OUT = tk.IntVar(root)
counter_DIFF = tk.IntVar(root)
   
# use textvariable to keep the labels updated
label_IN = tk.Label(root, textvariable=counter_IN)
label_OUT = tk.Label(root, textvariable=counter_OUT)
label_DIFF = tk.Label(root, textvariable=counter_DIFF)

# database polling
def counter_label_IN():
    def count():
        s.sendall(b'gcounters\x00')
        L_IN = next(iter(s.recv(1024)))
        print(L_IN)
        counter_IN.set(L_IN)  # update counter IntVar instead of label
        # update DIFF counter:
        diff = L_IN - counter_OUT.get()
        if diff < 0:
            diff = 0
        counter_DIFF.set(diff)
        label_IN.after(500, count)

    count()

def counter_label_OUT():
    def count():
        s.sendall(b'gcounters\x00')
        L_OUT = next(iter(s.recv(1024)))
        print(L_OUT)
        counter_OUT.set(L_OUT)  # update counter IntVar instead of label
        diff = counter_IN.get() - L_OUT
        if diff < 0:
            diff = 0
        counter_DIFF.set(diff)
        label_OUT.after(500, count)

    count()

# start monitoring the database
counter_label_IN()
counter_label_OUT()
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. I am a little lost and I guess it is one of those time the reply is right in front of my eyes but it is so bright that I cant see it...
The code written gives no error, but the counts displayed in all the labels are zeroes.

I will paste the complete code on the next reply.

Comment: @LorenzoAmati I could not fully test my code because I don't have the database part but from the code you posted I suspect that you just never execute the functions `counter_label_IN/OUT`. I used the same structure as in your code in the question, so to start monitoring the database you need to add `counter_label_IN()` (and the same for OUT) before starting the mainloop.

Comment: Thank you again @j_4321. I have edited the first post as you kindly pointed out, you can see the whole code now.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can now confirm that you never execute the `counter_label_IN/OUT` functions so the counters are never updated.

Comment: Dear @j_4321, thank you. I get a socket error now.. very odd. I have searched for that error and someone solved by disabling the firewall which I did, but no success... >_<

Comment: I won't be able to help you with socket errors, I don't know much about this. If you don't find a solution for them, I advise you to post a new question.